# How to change the element name in .asmx response?

Tags: web-services, asmx

The webservice returns xml like below. The consuming client is expecting < MyMethodResult > to be < Response >.

Code:

```
[WebMethod]
public MyResponseObj MyMethod(MyRequestObj Request)
{
    try
    {
        MyResponseObj response = new MyResponseObj();
        response.Message = "test";
        response.Status = Status.success;
        return response;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Actual Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <MyMethodResponse xmlns="MyNameSpace">
      <MyMethodResult>
        <Status>success or failure</Status>
        <Message>string</Message>
      </MyMethodResult>
    </MyMethodResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Expected Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <MyMethodResponse xmlns="MyNameSpace">
      **<Response>**
        <Status>success or failure</Status>
        <Message>string</Message>
      **</Response>**
    </MyMethodResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Where is the code used for generating it? Please provide that.

Comment: I updated my post with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by decorating the MyResponseObj class with `[XmlRoot("Response")]`

```
[XmlRoot("Response")]
public partial class MyResponseObj
{

}
```